# Heaviside theta integration with Mathematica

Tags: math, wolfram-mathematica, calculation

I am trying to integrate a Heaviside theta function with two signs inside and Mathematica won't give me a solution. Is there any way of improving the approach before just acknowledging that Mathematica cannot integrate it?

[image]

Comment: Would this question be better suited for https://math.stackexchange.com/?

Comment: @edtheprogrammerguy I am also posting it here because maybe some Mathematica tekky may help me, but sure it will also be posted there. Thanks!

Comment: No, it would better at [mathematica.stackexchange.com](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: @PresidentJamesK.Polk that is right

Answer (score 0):

Some things you do really worry me.

You use X as a variable and as the name of a function. I've changed those to X and Xf.

You use ω as a variable and as the name of a function. I've changed those to ω and ωf.

You use `=` and not `:=` in your function definitions. I've changed that.

With those changes I have

```
Xf[s1_,s2_,α_]:=(1+s2(-2+α)-α+s1(-1+2s2+α))/((-1+2 s1)(-1+2s2));
ωf[s1_,s2_,α_]:=((1-s2+s1(-3+4s2))(1+s2(-2+α)-α+s1(-1+2s2+α)))/((-1+2s1)(-1+s1+s2)(-1+2s2));
λ1[s1_,s2_,α_,X_,ω_]:=1/2(s1-2s2-3s1 X+3s2 X-α+s1 α+s2 α+ω-s1 ω-s2 ω-
  1/2Sqrt[(4(α-ω+s2(2-3X-α-ω)+s1(-1+3X-α+ω))^2+8(2-5X+4X^2-2α+2X α+
  s1(-2+4s2(1-2X)^2+7X-8X^2+2α-2X α-ω)+ω-s2(4-11X+8X^2-2α+2X α+ω)))]);
λ2[s1_,s2_,α_,X_,ω_]:=1/2(s1-2s2-3s1 X+3s2 X-α+s1 α+s2 α+ω-s1 ω-s2 ω+
  1/2Sqrt[(4(α-ω+s2(2-3X-α-ω)+s1(-1+3X-α+ω))^2+8(2-5X+4X^2-2α+2X α+
  s1(-2+4s2(1-2X)^2+7X-8X^2+2α-2X α-ω)+ω-s2(4-11X+8X^2-2α+2X α+ω)))]);
λ1simp[s1_,s2_,α_]:=λ1[s1,s2,α,Xf[s1,s2,α],ωf[s1,s2,α]];
λ2simp[s1_,s2_,α_]:=λ2[s1,s2,α,Xf[s1,s2,α],ωf[s1,s2,α]];
fint[s1_,s2_]:=HeavisideTheta[Sign[-λ1simp[s1,s2,α]]*Sign[-λ2simp[s1,s2,α]]];
```

Please check that very carefully to see if I've made any mistakes.

Now I want to look at your integrand and see what Mathematica sees.

```
Simplify[fint[s1,s2],1/2<=s1<=1&&1/2<=s2<=s1]
```

And it responds with

```
HeavisideTheta[CompexInfinity] 2s1==1||2s2==1||s1+s2==1
HeavisideTheta[True Sign[...]*Sign[...]]
```

so it looks like your integrand is blowing up at the boundary.

I check that with

```
Simplify[fint[1/2,s2]]
```

or

```
Simplify[fint[s1,1/2]]
```

and it responds with `1/0` and `Indeterminate` and `HeavisideTheta[Indeterminate]`

When it isn't at the boundary, for example

```
Simplify[fint[3/4,3/4]]
```

it returns

```
HeavisideTheta[Sign[5-4*Sqrt[7-28*α+25*α^2]]*Sign[5+4*Sqrt[7-28*α+25*α^2]]]
```

and that probably says that α is a free variable and we aren't able to determine the value of the Sign without more information.

So I think this is a strong hint where I would begin looking for why your integration is not simply completing.

If you are curious what that integrand looks like then try

```
α=1/4;
Plot3D[fint[s1,s2],{s1,1/2,1},{s2,1/2,s1}]
```